# HTML Table to paste multi datas in multi-cells

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I wanted to design a html table where i should be able to paste a table from google sheets to my html table
The problem is when i paste, all the datas are pasted in a single cell, they are not pasted as a table
I mean i wanted this

Row 1

Row 2

Row 3

to be pasted in three rows, instead it pastes in a single cell as Row 1 Row 2 Row 3

```html
<div class="tbldiv">
    <table class="table">
        <tr class="tr1">
            <td class="td"><input type="text"/></td>
            <td class="td"><input type="text"/></td>
            <td class="td"><input type="text"/></td>
            <td class="td"><input type="text"/></td>
            <td class="td"><input type="text"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr1">
            <td class="td"><input type="text"/></td>
            <td class="td"><input type="text"/></td>
            <td class="td"><input type="text"/></td>
            <td class="td"><input type="text"/></td>
            <td class="td"><input type="text"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr1">
            <td class="td"><input type="text"/></td>
            <td class="td"><input type="text"/></td>
            <td class="td"><input type="text"/></td>
            <td class="td"><input type="text"/></td>
            <td class="td"><input type="text"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your expected output example?

Comment: Where are you copying the data from?

Comment: Pasting from google sheets,